# Python: how can I override a complicated function during unittest?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am using Python's `unittest` module to test a script I am writing.

The script contains a loop like this:

```
// my_script.py

def my_loopy_function():
    aggregate_value = 0
    for x in range(10):
        aggregate_value = aggregate_value + complicated_function(x)
    return aggregate_value

def complicated_function(x):
    a = do()
    b = something()
    c = complicated()
    return a + b + c
```

I have no problems using `unittest` to test `complicated_function`. But I would like to test `my_loopy_function` by overriding `complicated_function`.

I tried modifying my script so that `my_loopy_function` takes `complicated_function` as an optional parameter so that I can pass in a simple version from the test:

```
// my_modified_script.py

def my_loopy_function(action_function=None):
    if action_function is not None:
        complicated_function = action_function
    aggregate_value = 0
    for x in range(10):
        aggregate_value = aggregate_value + complicated_function(x)
    return aggregate_value

def complicated_function(x):
    a = do()
    b = something()
    c = complicated()
    return a + b + c

// test_my_script.py

from myscript import my_loopy_function

class TestMyScript(unittest.TestCase):
    test_loopy_function(self):
        def simple_function():
            return 1
    self.assertEqual(10, my_loopy_function(action_function=simple_function))
```

It has not worked as I had hoped, are there any suggestions on how I should be doing this?

Comment: You can try using the `mock` package.  It's now part of Python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: How has it not worked as you hoped?

Comment: Yes I did see some references to mock. I get the feeling it might be the right thing for me here -- I basically want to override selected functions that get called in my code so that my tests can test the behaviour of the calling code.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden The problem that I am having is that I have a few tests running, and once I have overriden `complicated_function` with `simple_function` it stays pointing to `simple_function` even in a later test where I do not pass an '`action_function`'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I used Python's `mock`, which allows me to override `complicated_function` without having to adjust the original code in any way.

Here is the original script, and note that `complicated_function` is not passed in to `my_loopy_function` as an '`action_function`' parameter (which was what I tried in my earlier solutions):

```
// my_script.py

def my_loopy_function():
    aggregate_value = 0
    for x in range(10):
        aggregate_value = aggregate_value + complicated_function(x)
    return aggregate_value

def complicated_function(x):
    a = do()
    b = something()
    c = complicated()
    return a + b + c
```

and here is the script I am using to test it:

```
// test_my_script.py

import unittest
import mock
from my_script import my_loopy_function

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('my_script.complicated_function')
    def test_1(self, mocked):
        mocked.return_value = 1
        self.assertEqual(10, my_loopy_function())
```

This works just as I had wanted:

1. I am able to substitute functions with a simpler version of themselves that I can more easily test,
2. I do not need to alter my original code in any way (such as I was trying -- which was effectively by passing in function pointers), the `mock` module gives me post-coding access to the innards.

Thanks to austin for his suggestion to use `mock`.
BTW I am using Python 2.7 and therefore used the `pip`-installable `mock` from PyPI.

Comment: Up vote for self answer. Welcome to the mock word ... You'll discover a very wonderful framework to help your unit testing.

Comment: @Robert: Actually, I would call what you were doing before "mocking" as well. The difference is that here you're using the `mock` module to do the monkeypatching for you, and it's smart enough to reset the state after the SUT is complete.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried declaring an overriding `def foo()` both in the top-level and inside the test function and inside some random class at the top-level — it's always just ignored and the non-overriding function gets called instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to override `complicated_function` with `action_function`, just use `complicated_function` as the default `action_function`:

```
def my_loopy_function(action_function=complicated_function):
    aggregate_value = 0
    for x in range(10):
        aggregate_value = aggregate_value + action_function(x)
    return aggregate_value
```

Comment: I think I considered that correctly: if I just run `my_loopy_function` and use the default value of `None` for `action_function`, the loop will use that module's `complicated_function`, which is fine. But if I run it from my test script then I am simply overriding the `complicated_function` to actually point to `simple_function`.

Comment: I would leave the note, where the bug was. Now the code is, of course right, but it might be hard to spot why. At least one person didn't =).

Comment: @Robert It will behave the same, you just over-complicated logic. And you never use anything else than complicated function in your loop. That is the problem.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure what you meant to say in your comment here. Regardless, the pattern I'm describing is extremely common, and works — why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco fair points, I will definitely have a re-think.

Comment: That's a hack as this argument has nothing to do in the actual code. The arg is only for testing purposes, I'm not sure it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you shouldn't be able to overwrite `complicated_function` like that. If I try it, I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'complicated_function' referenced before assignment`.

But perhaps is the problem that in your actual code, you're referring to `complicated_function` in some other way (e.g. as a member of a module)? Then by overwriting it in your test, you're overwriting the actual `complicated_function`, so you won't be able to use it from other tests.

The correct way to do this is to overwrite the *local* variable with the global one, like so:

```
def my_loopy_function(action_function=None):
  if action_function is None:
    action_function = complicated_function
  aggregate_value = 0
    for x in range(10):
      # Use action_function here instead of complicated_function
      aggregate_value = aggregate_value + action_function(x)
    return aggregate_value
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. You are right that my overwriting means that later tests cannot use the original complicated_function.
I am looking into mocking the complicated_function. I like the idea of being able to overwrite functions in my code so that I can test 'from the outside in' rather than 'from the unit out'.

Comment: Robert: I don't understand what you mean by "from the outside in" here -- either way, you're injecting a mock/shim for testing purposes. (You're *already* mocking `complicated_function` by replacing the real implementation with a fake one.) The difference is that you're proposing doing this by mutating global state (the `complicated_function` function is a global object), and I'm proposing doing this by local logic in your `my_loopy_function` function. It's always best to avoid mutating global state if possible, as it leads to exactly these kinds of problems, which can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make `@mock.patch` from the accepted answer work in any combination *(worth noting I'm using pytest, but then the answer seems to be testing library-agnostic, so Idk)*, but I found a more generic way to do that, so sharing.

There's a technique called "monkey-patching". Its purpose is exactly to override a method from a 3rd party module. It works both with top-level functions as well as with class methods *(in the latter case you need to add a class name in the assignment operation)*.

It works like this: you first do `import some_module` and then to override its function `foo` to `bar` you execute `some_module.foo = bar`.

**Important**: the module should be imported **without** `from`. I.e. if you do a `from some_module import foo` and then `foo = bar`, it will not work.

Example:

```hs
λ cat some_module.py
def hello():
    print("hello")

def some_func():
    hello()
λ cat test.py
import some_module

def my_override():
    print("hi")

some_module.hello = my_override

some_module.some_func()
λ python3 test.py
hi
```